# Translate from MCInst to ELF Binary in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, llvm, elf

I am doing an LLVM project aimed to disassemble an ARM ELF binary executable to the *MCInst* format, inserting some instructions or doing some modification, and re-assemble the *MCInst* to an ELF binary.

I used llvm-objdump to do the first part of the job. But after searching for a long time, I still cannot figure out how to translate the *MCInst* back to a binary.

Could anyone kindly tell me which tool or function of LLVM is useful for doing this? And what is the best way to store the intermediate *MCInst*? e.g., store them just in memory or store them in a file, which function could store and read them in a decent way?

I really appreciate any of your help, even just one point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a full answer because what you're trying to do is not explicitly exposed from LLVM for external use. But I do have some pointers which should lead you to the solution after some code reading.

The tool you want to look at is `tools/llvm-mc/llvm-mc.cpp`. When it does assembly, it goes through the steps of parsing ASM, creating MC-level data structures from it and emitting them into an ELF file (or some other file). These actions are implemented in some helper classes, which are quite strongly coupled; this is why you need to look at the tool to see how they're used in unison. The main class you want to look at is `MCAssembler`. It uses an "emitter" to actually emit `MCInst`s into binary form.

An emitter is (naturally) target-specific. For example `ARMMCCodeEmitter`, etc. Note that the MC-level representation of a binary is not only `MCInst`s, though. There are directives, stuff to deal with sections and so on. This is why it's important to study what `MCAssembler` does.